# 'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, rc

I am trying to create a resoure file using VS command prompt.

I am using the following code:

```
     TlbExp.exe /win32 MyMenu.dll
     echo 1 typelib MyMenu.tlb > MyMenu.rc
     rc.exe MyMenu.rc
```

I have the MyMenu.dll and the MyMenu.rc file saved in the same folder but for some reason it will not recognise the rc command to create a resource file.

Would appreciate any help or ideas. Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Developer Command Prompt?

Comment: Yes I am for VS 2019

Comment: Might need to reinstall one of the SDKs. Not sure which one `rc.exe` is in, but clearly appears to be missing. Or your Developer Command Prompt is missing a `PATH` variable, you will have to search for it

Comment: rc.exe is not a C# tool so the VS installer didn't deploy it when you selected the ".NET desktop development" workload.  It requires the "Desktop development with C++" workload or (smaller) Individual Components > SDK, libraries and frameworks > Windows 10 SDK.  The version doesn't matter much, I have 10.0.19041.0

Comment: I reinstalled some SDKs and used powershell command promprt and  that seemed to do the trick